# DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer webflux error

Tags: java, spring, webclient, spring-webflux

While sending a file I receive an array of bytes. I always have a problem with webflux to receive an array.
the error thrown as below :

```
org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144
    at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.LimitedDataBufferList.raiseLimitException(LimitedDataBufferList.java:101)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException
```

Do you now how to resolve that in webflux ?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23961

Comment: You can also refer: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-databufferlimitexception

Comment: Most (all?) of the answers suggest ways to configure the size of the buffer.  I presume there is no alternative.  This feels like an WebClient API failure.  The implementation should grow the backing buffer when required much like an ArrayList will grow the backing array when required.

Answer (score 164):

This worked for me:

1. Create a `@Bean` in one of your configuration classes or the main `SpringBootApplication` class:

   ```java
   @Bean
   public WebClient webClient() {
       final int size = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
       final ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
           .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(size))
           .build();
       return WebClient.builder()
           .exchangeStrategies(strategies)
           .build();
   }
   ```
2. Next, go to your desired class where you want to use the `WebClient`:

   ```java
   @Service
   public class TestService {

       @Autowired
       private WebClient webClient;

       public void test() {
           String out = webClient
               .get()
               .uri("/my/api/endpoint")
               .retrieve()
               .bodyToMono(String.class)
               .block();

           System.out.println(out);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Don't know why, this the only solution that worked on WebFlux 2.3.2.RELEASE

Comment: If you have declared a custom web configuration (ex. by implementing WebMvcConfigurer), you override the option in properties.yaml. Thus, if you set the `maxInMemorySize` property, you configure directly your webclient, bypassing the Web Configuration of spring-boot.

Answer (score 91):

I suppose this issue is about adding a new `spring.codec.max-in-memory-size` configuration property in Spring Boot. Add it to the `application.yml` file like:

```yaml
spring:
  codec:
    max-in-memory-size: 10MB
```

Comment: I'm using this in my spring boot app config, however it doesn't help.

Comment: @mareck_ste Hi! Maybe you are using some custom configuration that overrides this option. E.g. you have WebClient configuration, so just set this 'maxInMemorySize' property in that WebClientBuilder.exchangeStrategies()

Comment: @mareck_ste indeed, I have the same for spring-boot-starter-webflux 2.3.5-RELEASE . Check out this [excelent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59392022/1610553)

Comment: Thank you Bernard, modifying the codecs worked.

Comment: If the config-based solution above does not work - the following might explain why - you need to be using the pre-configured Spring WebClient.Builder and not creating your own https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27836

Comment: In my case, I needed to put this setting in the API gateway settings rather than the endpoint service settings.

Answer (score 32):

Set the maximum **bytes** (in **megabytes**) in your **Spring Boot** `application.properties` configuration file like below:

```
spring.codec.max-in-memory-size=20MB
```

Comment: If that doesn't work this might be why https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27836

Answer (score 29):

This is the official way ([see documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-webclient/client-builder.html#webflux-client-builder-maxinmemorysize)) to get rid of the exception:

```
webTestClient.mutate()
  .codecs(configurer -> configurer
          .defaultCodecs()
          .maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024))
  .build().get()
  .uri("/u/r/l")
  .exchange()
  .expectStatus()
  .isOk()
```

Comment: Thank you!! Not sure why properties or bean for webclient didn't work for me but this did!

Comment: Just to add on this answer, "codecs" is the important part.

Answer (score 17):

i was getting this error for a simple RestController (i post a large json string).

here is how i successfully changed the `maxInMemorySize`

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebfluxConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui.html**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024);
    }
}
```

this was surprisingly hard to find

Comment: Why are you showing the addResourceHandlers method? Is it related to the question somehow?

Answer (score 17):

Instead of retrieving data at once, you can stream:

```
Mono<String> string = webClient.get()
    .uri("end point of an API")
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
    .map(buffer -> {
        String string = buffer.toString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        DataBufferUtils.release(buffer);
        return string;
    });
```

Alternatively convert to stream:

```
    .map(b -> b.asInputStream(true))
    .reduce(SequenceInputStream::new)
    .map(stream -> {
        // consume stream
        stream.close();
        return string;
    });
```

In most cases you don't want to really aggregate the stream, rather than processing it directly. The need to load huge amount of data in memory is mostly a sign to change the approach to more reactive one. JSON- and XML-Parsers have streaming interfaces.

Comment: Where is `buffer` defined?

Comment: @AshokKoyi I mixed up two variants before (fixed)

Comment: Did you actually measure the overall memory footprint? i.e even after releasing the data buffer, unless you consume the final stream, the memory will still piled up since you are using reduction till you receive last byte. So, I am not sure whether you will have any advantage by using this approach

Comment: Option (1) is problematic as you are not guaranteed that you received all the data before you can convert it the bytes to string. Its possible that we only read 1 byte of a 4 byte UTF-8 character during the map operation

Comment: If the partial data can be utilised & the buffer be freed, that's the best thing that can be done. Using reductions is a bad idea as we are filling the memory till complete reduction is done, which defeats the point of using buffers as and when they come. Option (1) is valid, but it only works as a byte array, not as string

Comment: Looks like Jackson bombs when it comes to streamed parsing based on this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416158/how-to-properly-parse-streaming-json-with-jackson

Comment: I absolutely aggree, as told: "In most cases you don't want to really aggregate the stream"

Comment: The idea is the best one among all answers here. The only thing I don't like in the presented example code is this call to `DataBufferUtils.release(buffer)`. Smells like manual memory management which is so against general Java.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me

```
val exchangeStrategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                .codecs { configurer: ClientCodecConfigurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024) }.build()
        return WebClient.builder().exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies).build()
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative could be creating a custom `CodecCustomizer`, which is going to be applied to both `WebFlux` and `WebClient` at the same time:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class MyAppConfiguration {

    companion object {
        private const val MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 50 * 1024 * 1024 // 50 MB
    }

    @Bean
    fun codecCustomizer(): CodecCustomizer {
        return CodecCustomizer {
            it.defaultCodecs()
                .maxInMemorySize(MAX_MEMORY_SIZE)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Spring Boot 2.3.0, there is now a dedicated configuration property for the Reactive Elasticsearch REST client.

You can use the following configuration property to set a specific memory limit for the client.

spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.max-in-memory-size=
The already existing spring.codec.max-in-memory-size property is separate and only affects other WebClient instances in the application.

Comment: This is replaces with spring.elasticsearch.webclient.max-in-memory-size=512MB [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73921961/5557885)

Answer (score 0):

For those who had no luck with the myriad of beans, customizers, and properties that could be added to solve this problem, check whether you have defined a bean extending `WebFluxConfigurationSupport`. If you have, it will disable the autoconfiguration version of the same bean (my personal experience, Boot 2.7.2), somewhere under which Spring loads properties such as the suggested `spring.codec.max-in-memory-size`. For this solution to work you need to have also configured this property correctly.

To test if this is the cause of your problems, remove your `WebFluxConfigurationSupport` implementation temporarily. The long term fix that worked for me was to use configuration beans to override attributes for the autoconfigured bean. In my case, `WebFluxConfigurer` had all of the same methods available and was a drop-in replacement for `WebFluxConfigurationSupport`. Large JSON messages are now decoding for me as configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to change the default settings for webClient globally, you can use the following approach to manually merge multiple DataBuffers

```
webClient
        .method(GET)
        .uri("<uri>")
        .exchangeToMono(response -> {
          return response.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
              .switchOnFirst((firstBufferSignal, responseBody$) -> {
                assert firstBufferSignal.isOnNext();
                return responseBody$
                    .collect(() -> requireNonNull(firstBufferSignal.get()).factory().allocateBuffer(), (accumulator, curr) -> {
                      accumulator.ensureCapacity(curr.readableByteCount());
                      accumulator.write(curr);
                      DataBufferUtils.release(curr);
                    })
                    .map(accumulator -> {
                      final var responseBodyAsStr = accumulator.toString(UTF_8);
                      DataBufferUtils.release(accumulator);
                      return responseBodyAsStr;
                    });
              })
              .single();
        });
```

The above code aggregates all the `DataBuffer`s into a single `DataBuffer` & then converts the final `DataBuffer` into a string. Please note that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63374941/211794) wont work as DataBuffers received might not have all the bytes to construct a character (incase of UTF-8 characters, each character can take upto 4 bytes). So we cant convert intermediate `DataBuffer`s into String as the bytes towards
the end of buffer might have only part of the bytes required to construct a valid character

Note that this loads all the response `DataBuffer`s into memory but unlike changing global settings for the `webClient` across the whole application. You can use this option to read complete response only where you want i.e you can narrow down & pick this option only where you expect large responses.

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring boot 2.7.x we should use below property to set the memory size to webclient which is used internally in reactive ElasticSearch

`spring.elasticsearch.webclient.max-in-memory-size=512MB`

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code in your springboot main class.

```
@Bean
public WebClient getWebClient() {
    return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("Your_SERVICE_URL")
            .codecs(configurer -> configurer
                      .defaultCodecs()
                      .maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024))
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
}
```

This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're using custom decoder, you need to set the maximum in-memory size in there, for instance:

```
Integer CODEC_20_MB_SIZE = 20 * 1024 * 1024;
WebClient.builder()
    .codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> {
        var codec = new Jackson2JsonDecoder();
        codec.setMaxInMemorySize(CODEC_20_MB_SIZE);
        clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().register(codec);
        clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().register(new Jackson2JsonEncoder());
    });
```