# Set Max In Memory Size In Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am receiving the following error in a Spring Boot application using WebFlux

> org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded
> limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144

I tried setting the limit inside `application.yml` with

```yaml
spring:
  codec:
    max-in-memory-size: 10MB
```

Or by adding the following to a WebClient configuration class but they are ignored.

```java
.exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder()
        .codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> clientCodecConfigurer
                .defaultCodecs()
                .maxInMemorySize(10 * 1024 * 1024)
        )
        .build()
)
```

I am Using Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE.

Do you have any idea on what the problem might be?

Comment: Do you even need that much in memory? It could be a streaming issue with your code where you build up more than you should in memory.

Comment: since we have no idea how the usage is when you are getting it i will just point ju to the documentation about different limits in webflux https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs-limits

Comment: If you use Spring cloud, then this question might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62415728/spring-cloud-hoxton-sr5-issue-with-eureka-and-webflux-exceeded-limit-on-max-byt

Comment: it depends on where this is being thrown and the codec used. Could you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: @CDan, did you get the solution? I am also facing same problem and no solution from other references is working...

Answer (score 2):

you can add the following configuration:

[image]

[image]