# Limits for codecs in spring

Tags: java, spring, webclient, httpresponse, codec

I was getting following exception while using Web Client.

```
org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144
```

which indicated that codec limit has to be increased via ***[MaxInMemorySize](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/CodecConfigurer.DefaultCodecs.html#maxInMemorySize-int-)*** property.

I wanted to understand if MaxInMemorySize is set to X, does that mean for every request our application puts aside X amount of memory for buffering upfront or that the memory is assigned dynamically as per the response size of each request.

Answer (score 1):

Spring maintains some amount of buffer which is MaxInMemorySize (around 250KB). This can be modified by adding a property to the application.properties / application.yml.

example:

`spring.codec.max-in-memory-size: 10MB`

By adding this, the max in memory size will be increased to 10MB.

Coming to your question, since this is a predefined value, the spring internally creates some buffer rather than creating individually for each request.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar error updating the below property in spring-boot application.yml helped resolve this error.

```
spring:
  codec:
    max-in-memory-size: 700KB
```

you can change the default DataBufferLimit using the above property.

You can find more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59735951/databufferlimitexception-exceeded-limit-on-max-bytes-to-buffer-webflux-error)