# How to process large response using Spring WebClient without buffering it first

Tags: buffer, spring-webclient

We want to process large response (tens of MB) using Spring WebClient. We are encountering `org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59735951/databufferlimitexception-exceeded-limit-on-max-bytes-to-buffer-webflux-error). But we do not want to increase the buffer size. We are only using a small subset of the response so if there is a way to directly pipe the response stream to Jackson for de-serialization, we could spare lots of unnecessary memory allocations. Is it possible to skip the buffer or not?

Comment: unless you're dealing with a streaming response (i.e. multiple messages), you'd end up with the same problem: you'll be buffering the whole thing in memory with Jackson since you can't really deserialize a JSON document until it's completely there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's not possible. At the end we switched to plain OkHttp client and it handles the same load without any issue.